# linux COM port write and read

Tags: linux, shell

I have a COM port connected to my Linux host, namely `/dev/ttySx`, how can I simply write and read some data from this COM port in shell, like use `echo` and `cat` command?

Comment: You may be looking for [`dd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)).

Comment: First run `minicom` or something like that for set up tty port, second - use `cat`. Another way - using something like `com` from `tinyserial` package. But I'd rather advice you to use C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo cat /dev/ttySx` will help in reading from that port. `echo "something" | tee /dev/ttySx` will help you writing to that port.

But mind that you might have to setup baud rate first in case of some device.

Comment: can I set baud rate in shell as well?

Comment: I guess setserial does that

Answer (score 0):

Use `stty .... < /dev/ttyS1`.

[man stty](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/stty.1.php) will give you the details.